# Get EditText input values and display some calculation result in an TextView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have made a very basic weighted average calculator as Android Application (in Java) and it worked fine.

The user just inputs 3 values `a`, `b`, `c` in three `EditText`s and it calculates formula:

```
d = 0.25 * a + 0.25 * b + 0.5 * c;
```

Result of this mathematical equation is displayed in a `TextView`, all of this in the `MainActivity` at the press of a button.

But after creating a new project for better UI (used Android Studio template Navigation Drawer Activity) I realized that my code is not working.

How could i modify that calculator to get input in my fragment (named `CalculatorWeightedFragment`) to make calculations and display the result in a TextView in the same fragment when my button is pressed?

At this point all I'm getting is the display of something static and no action assigned to the button.

The code is below:

**CalculatorWeightedFragment.java**

```
public class CalculatorWeightedFragment extends Fragment {

    private CalculatorWeightedViewModel calculatorWeightedViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        calculatorWeightedViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(calculatorWeightedViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator_w, container, false);

        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.id_result);  // result d stored in id_result


        calculatorWeightedViewModel.takeText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable String str) {
                        textView.setText(str);
                    }
                });

        return root;
    }
}
```

**CalculatorWeightedViewModel.java**

```
public class CalculatorWeightedViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> testString;

    public CalculatorWeightedViewModel() {
        testString = new MutableLiveData<>();
        testString.setValue("" + 0.5);
    }

    public LiveData<String> takeText() {
        return testString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Which part is not working? Where do you have `EditText`s (I do not see them in current code)?

Comment: _At this point all I'm getting is the display of something static and no action assigned to the button_ - in your code there is no OnClickListener set.

Comment: @Boken tried several ways but I don't know how to read those EditTexts to this new project. In the initial phase, everything was in Main Activity, but now I can't get findViewbyId to work anymore.

Comment: @CosminD what you are trying to add? This new fragment?

Comment: The cleaned XML part is       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_b" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_c" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_buton_rata"
        android:onClick="calculateFunction" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_d" />

Comment: @Boken Basically I'm trying to: 1. be able to read the EditTexts and make calculations 2. output the calculated value in a TextView. But now I use fragments instead of seeing everything in Main...I'm a complete stranger to fragments, and ViewModels...I can't reuse my old code.

Comment: @Mohru you are totally right, but I mixed two problems in one: reading edittext data + buttons. I hope I can clear them one at a time.

Comment: @CosminD Are all of your views in Fragment (`EditText`s, `Button` and `TextView`) or something is in Activity? Why do you need ViewModel in that?

Comment: @Boken I've read a lot of developer pages and blogs on the subject. For future development, I want to keep the logic away from my Views. Still fighting to put it all together. Right now each fragment will have other functions, nothing in Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your xml layout content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_buton_rata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="calculateFunction" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Example #1 (without `LiveData` and `ViewModel`)

I create some new simple fragment (as example)

```
public class CalculatorWeightedFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editTextA;
    private EditText editTextB;
    private EditText editTextC;
    private TextView textViewD;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator_w, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.id_buton_rata);
        editTextA = view.findViewById(R.id.id_a);
        editTextB = view.findViewById(R.id.id_b);
        editTextC = view.findViewById(R.id.id_c);
        textViewD = view.findViewById(R.id.id_result);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double result = calculateResult();
                String output = String.format("Result:  %s", result);
                textViewD.setText(output);
            }
        });
    }

    private double calculateResult() {
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(editTextA.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(editTextB.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(editTextC.getText().toString());

            // Result
            return 0.25 * a + 0.25 * b + 0.5 * c;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

## Example #2 (with `LiveData` and `ViewModel`)

When you are using `LiveData` and `ViewModel`, you no need button in your `Fragment`. You can observe all of the changes.

Activity where you are creating this fragment. To have ViewModel in Fragment, you can use dependency injection (e.g. using Dagger library) or get it from `ViewModelProviders` (or `AndroidViewModelFactory`).

Here, to make example as simple as possible, I'm passing it via constructor.

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CalculatorWeightedViewModel vm = new CalculatorWeightedViewModel();

        CalculatorWeightedFragment fragment = new CalculatorWeightedFragment(vm);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

You can store you values (`a`, `b`, `c`) as fieldsfor different purpose. Here, I'm recalculating result live, without any extra fiels. To make it as simple as possible.

```
package com.example.stack_android;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class CalculatorWeightedViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> testString = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<String> takeText() {
        return testString;
    }

    void updateValues(double a, double b, double c) {
        double result = recalculate(a, b, c);
        String value = "Result: " + result;
        testString.postValue(value);
    }

    void showError() {
        testString.postValue("Wrong Value");
    }

    private double recalculate(double a, double b, double c) {
        return 0.25 * a + 0.25 * b + 0.5 * c;
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

Additionaly you can create separate listeners (for each of the fields). Here, I'm using one (named `TextWatcher listener`) for all of the fields.

```
public class CalculatorWeightedFragment extends Fragment {

    private CalculatorWeightedViewModel viewModel;

    private EditText editTextA;
    private EditText editTextB;
    private EditText editTextC;
    private TextView textViewD;

    public CalculatorWeightedFragment(CalculatorWeightedViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator_w, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        editTextA = view.findViewById(R.id.id_a);
        editTextB = view.findViewById(R.id.id_b);
        editTextC = view.findViewById(R.id.id_c);
        textViewD = view.findViewById(R.id.id_result);

        TextWatcher listener = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // Not used
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Not used
            }
        };

        editTextA.addTextChangedListener(listener);
        editTextB.addTextChangedListener(listener);
        editTextC.addTextChangedListener(listener);

        viewModel.takeText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String newValue) {
                textViewD.setText(newValue);
            }
        });
    }

    private void textChanged() {
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(editTextA.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(editTextB.getText().toString());
            int c = Integer.parseInt(editTextC.getText().toString());

            viewModel.updateValues(a, b, c);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            viewModel.showError();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It should works like there:

[image: Demo]

Comment: I went with example #2 and reconstructed my project, but I got some runtime error unfortunately. I think some mismatch with the navigation layout..  2020-04-20 04:00:33.433 27583-27583/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-04-20 04:00:33.434 27583-27583/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-04-20 04:00:33.455 27583-27583/? E/ulatorfinancia: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-04-20 04:00:33.687 27583-27583/com.kd.calculatorfinanciar E/AndroidRuntime:

Comment: I think that there is another `exception` in the code. Please add new question with whole stacktrace, so we can close this one, and will try to fix new problem.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kd.calculatorfinanciar, PID: 27583
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kd.calculatorfinanciar/com.kd.calculatorfinanciar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.kd.calculatorfinanciar:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.kd.calculatorfinanciar:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3555)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2220)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)

Comment: Please add new question with new problem.

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.kd.calculatorfinanciar:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.kd.calculatorfinanciar:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.kd.calculatorfinanciar:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: sure, anyway somehow I think it relates to FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();     I don't have a resource frame_layout

Comment: Ah! You have to adapt your Activity to your project. Here, I'm showing you how to can pass `ViewModel` from Activity in to Fragment. My `frame_layout` it's `FrameLayout` which I'm using for putting Framgnents there.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use textwatcher in every edittext Follow [this Artical](https://computerpathsala.com/get-edittext-input-values-and-display-some-calculation-result-in-an-textview-live-calculation-in-android/)